# Including check box to each row of my data in database using php and html

Tags: php, html

I have a table called idean5 which has my data.And i'm displaying that data using php on my webpage ,now i want to add a tick box for each row of my data,actually i want to move particular rows from this table idean5 to other table called idean4. so when some one ticks the boxes and click on a move hyperlink button.this data should be moved.

code for this:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
require_once('auth.php');    //include of db config file
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page

$per_page = 15;         // number of results to show per page
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM idean5");
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);//total pages we going to have

//-------------if page is setcheck------------------//
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = intval($_GET['page']);
  if ($page <= 0){
    $page = 1;}
    $show_page = $_GET['page'];             //it will telles the current page
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
        $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
    } else {
        // error - show first set of results
        $start = 0;              
        $end = $per_page;
    }
} else {
    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page;
}
// display pagination


$tpages=$total_pages;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { background: #eee url() no-repeat center 0px; padding-top:5px;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: center;
    padding: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: green;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
.logo
{
    text-align: center;
}
.container{

}
</style>
<h3 align="right">WELCOME <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];?>!</h3>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="requestinput.php">REQUEST FOR TND</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">UPLOAD TND</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="displayingrequests.php">TND REQUESTS</a>
      <a href="import.php">UPLOAD TND</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li><a href="Combined_Status.php">STATUS SEARCH</a></li>
  <li><a href="testformsimple.php">SEARCH</a></li>
  <li><a href="approvalinput.php">APPROVAL</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php">LOGOUT</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo">


                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

                 <?php
                    $reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;
                    echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
                    if ($total_pages > 1) {
                        echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
                    }

                    echo "</ul></div>";
                    // display data in table
                    echo "<table border='1'>                  
                    <tr>
                    <th>TND ID</th>
                    <th>Site Name S1</th>
                    <th>Site Name S2</th>
                    <th>Idea ID S1</th>
                    <th>Idea ID S2</th>
                    <th>O N M Remarks</th>
                    <th>Planning Remarks</th>
                    <th>Projects Remarks</th>

                    </tr>";
                    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
                    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
                        // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
                        if ($i == $total_results) {
                            break;
                        }

                        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'TND_ID') . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Site_name_S1') . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Site_name_S2') . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Idea_ID_S1') . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Idea_ID_S2') . '</td>';
                        if (mysql_result($result, $i, 'O_M_Remarks')) {
                           echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'O_M_Remarks').'</td>';
                        }
                        else {
                          echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'O_M_Remarks') . '<a href="o&mstatusinput.php ? TND_ID='.mysql_result($result, $i, 'TND_ID').'">O N M remarks</a> </td>';
                        }
                        if (mysql_result($result, $i, 'Planning_Remarks')) {
                           echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Planning_Remarks').'</td>';
                        }
                        else {
                          echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Planning_Remarks') . '<a href="planningstatusinput.php ? TND_ID='.mysql_result($result, $i, 'TND_ID').'">Planning remarks</a> </td>';
                        }
                        if (mysql_result($result, $i, 'O_M_Remarks')) {
                           echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Projects_Remarks').'</td>';
                        }
                        else {
                          echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Projects_Remarks') . '<a href="projectsstatusinput.php ? TND_ID='.mysql_result($result, $i, 'TND_ID').'">Projects remarks</a> </td>';
                        }

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }       
                    // close table>
                echo "</table>";
            // pagination
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put `<input type="checkbox">` in each row of the form.

Comment: i am new to coding..can u tell where to put that satement in the above code.

Comment: You echo it just like any other HTML that you're creating in PHP. You need to give the input a name. There are many tutorials on the web about how to create web forms and process them with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In "//echo out the contents of each row into a table" portion. try this at this.

```
<td>input type="checkbox"></td>
```

For loop will automatically add checkbox in each row.

Comment: it is dispalying error,when i put that statement near that...i think that echo part is under php ,because of that ..im getting error....

Comment: if i put that statement aboveor below the php part ,then it is displaying the check box

Comment: you should write in echo